# Prolog-Sum positive numbers from a List

Tags: list, sum, prolog

I have the following Prolog fact to sum the positive numbers from a list but it´s not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
somarPositivos([],0).
somarPositivos([H|T],Soma):-H>0,somarPositivos(T,Soma1),Soma is Soma1+H.
somarPositivos([H|T],Soma):-H=<0 ,somarPositivos(T,Soma1).
```

Comment: somar is an infinitive, de facto imperative. Instead try to use nouns and relate them like  `números _soma/2` (`numbers_sum/2`). or somapos... By using the plural números we indicate that we have a list of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the third clause. It should be:

```
somarPositivos([H|T],Soma):-H=<0 ,somarPositivos(T,Soma).
```

Most Prolog compilers would print a warning that the variables `Soma` and `Soma1` are *singleton variables* in that clause.

Some notes on programming style following Prolog coding guidelines. Indent your code. Use spaces around operators. Use underscores instead of camelCase for predicate names for readbility. Thus, preferably write:

```
somar_positivos([],0).
somar_positivos([H|T],Soma) :-
    H > 0,
    somar_positivos(T,Soma1),
    Soma is Soma1+H.
somar_positivos([H|T],Soma) :-
    H =< 0,
    somar_positivos(T,Soma).
```

As an improvement to this initial version of the predicate, can you rewrite it to make it *tail-recursive* using an accumulator?

Comment: Apparently called [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Prolog is not mentioned in the Wikipedia list though. More on page 14 of [Coding Guidelines for Prolog](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899).

Comment: underscored_names are anathema to Haskellers, who are urged to always use camelCase. :) :) go figure. :)